# FBD for TwinCat Beckhoff... Function Block Input Output How is this working

Tags: plc, twincat

Seems IW_PR_Schrittnummer is only referenced in 3 spots... where it's declared and where its read in the fbd routine... I guess what I'm asking is something writing a number to this variable... or what? If so how would I find it... also what is the action being performed by this first function block? looks like there are 4 inputs, Auto, is Auto Active, does tasknumber = 0, and is Press Free. if all 4 of these are true... then End Auto. Does that sound right??? someone else programmed this for a job that does work. The tags are in German.

[1st FBD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6H1G.png)

[Variable Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoACx.png)

[Variable Declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lehov.png)

[2nd fbd just for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRQbu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IW_PR_Schrittnummer` is linked to input I/O using `AT %ID716` command. So it gets its value from I/O memory. That basically means that "take this value from input memory at address 716 and the size is D (double word, 32 bits).

I'm not sure how you can check what is in that address when it's defined with direct addressing like this. Hopefully someone else knows a good tip for this!

More info about addresses: https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/18014401038842507.html&id=6547931155168793261

More info about addresses: https://help.codesys.com/webapp/_cds_at_declaration;product=codesys;version=3.5.15.0

That logic from your 1st image works as you said. So `AutoFinde` will be TRUE, if `Auto`, `AutoAktiv`, `IstFrei` are all TRUE and the input `IW_PR_Schrittnummer` is 0. Otherwise the `AutoFinde` will always be FALSE.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I appreciate it! That definitely helped me 

Comment: Glad to hear that!